# Will the dead mice I found in my compost tea poison my veggies?

Tags: compost-tea

I poured compost tea on all my vegetables in the garden. Afterwards I found two dead mice at the bottom of the bucket. Do I need to pull up my plants and throw them away?

Comment: Are you planning to eat the vegetables very soon?

Comment: Thank you they are new veggie starts so I won’t plan to eat them for another two months or so. plants like collard greens, broccoli, spinach, and lettuce

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the plants.  If they are bushy plants like tomatoes or capsicum, there are no problems.  But if they are lower plants such as cabbage or cauliflower or they are root veges such as carrots then you need to not harvest them for at least 2 maybe 3 weeks.

You should also wash your hands thoroughly and keep a lookout for [symptoms](https://fodcas.com/i-accidentally-touched-a-dead-mouse/) such as

> High fever
> Headache
> Chills
> Muscle aches
> Vomiting
> Jaundice (yellow skin and eyes)
> Red eyes
> Abdominal pain
> Diarrhea
> Rash\